# Laravel not grabbing FormData values sent by Flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter

I have a Flutter app which connected with an API created using Laravel. I want to post a data with images and store it to the database.

I'm using `dio` package as the `http` communicator. I already created the algorithm to process the form submission but it seems like laravel couldn't grab it's parameters.

Any idea?

Please have a look at my scripts below:

`Submit Script`

```dart
// A method that submitting the form to the server to be stored
// on database.
void _submit() async {
  setState(() => _isSubmitting = true);

  try {
    List<MultipartFile> files;

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      final ByteData byteData = await images[i].getByteData(quality: 80);
      final List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

      final MultipartFile file = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        imageData,
        filename: images[i].name,
        contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'),
      );

      files.add(file);
    }

    final List<int> participants =
        _taggedEmployees.map((employee) => employee.id).toList();

    final FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'title': _title,
      'chronology': _chronology,
      'images': files,
      'participants': participants,
    });

    final Response response = await Request.post('fieldReports', formData);

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      setState(() => _isSubmitting = false);
      print('Upload success!');
      print(response.data.toString());
    } else {
      setState(() => _isSubmitting = false);
      debugPrint('==================== ERROR ====================');
      debugPrint(response.toString());
      debugPrint('==================== END OF ERROR ====================');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    setState(() => _isSubmitting = false);
    debugPrint('==================== EXCERROR ====================');
    debugPrint(e.toString());
    debugPrint('==================== END OF EXCERROR ====================');
  }
}
```

`Request.dart`

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:prismahrmobile/utilities/logging_interceptors.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Request {
  static Dio get dio => _dio();

  static Dio _dio() {
    // Configure base options for dio package.
    final BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: DotEnv().env['BASE_API_URL'],
      connectTimeout: 5000,
      receiveTimeout: 5000,
      followRedirects: false,
      headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // 'Accept': 'application/json',
      },

      /// perceive as successful if status code is less than 500 (Server Error)
      /// so that the app doesn't break when there is any validation
      /// errors from the server.
      validateStatus: (statusCode) {
        return statusCode < 500;
      },
    );

    // Initiate dio with the provided options.
    Dio dio = Dio(options);

    dio.interceptors.add(LoggingInterceptors());
    dio.interceptors.add(
      InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions options) async {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final String token = prefs.getString('accessToken');

        options.headers.addAll({
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        });

        return options;
      }),
    );

    return dio;
  }

  // Send a get request based on the provided url.
  static Future<Response> get(String url) async {
    return await dio.get(url);
  }

  // Send a post request based on the provided url with the data.
  static Future<Response> post(String url, dynamic data) async {
    return await dio.post(url, data: data);
  }
}
```

`Store method -- FieldReportController.php`

```php
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\RequestFieldReport  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(RequestFieldReport $request)
{
    $fieldReport = $this->data($request, $this->storeImages($request));
    $fieldReport->participants()->sync($request->participants);

    return response()->json([
        'created' => true,
        'data' => $fieldReport,
    ], 201);
}
```

`RequestFieldReport.php`

```php
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'sometimes|required|numeric',
        'employee_id' => 'sometimes|required|numeric',
        'title' => 'required|string|unique:field_reports,name,' . $this->id . ',id,employee_id,' . $this->employee_id,
        'chronology' => 'required|string|max:300',
        'participants' => 'required|array',
        'images' => 'sometimes|required|array',
        'images.*' => 'file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    ];
}
```

Response from the server:

```
Response: {message: The given data was invalid., errors: {title: [The title field is required.], chronology: [The chronology field is required.], participants: [The participants field is required.]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem, the reason it happened is because I made a little mistake, I forgot to put a `setState` inside the `onChange` event of the `TextField` which is leading to a `null` value for the `_title`, and `_chronology` field.

Everything works fine now.